# No puedo conectarme LDAP con Centos 7 y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, centos, centos7, lumen

Tengo desarrollada una api con Lumen, tiene instalado LDAP donde realizo la utenticacion por ese medio.
Pude conectarme correctamente a un entorno de prueba con https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ , en un entorno local funciona correctamente pero cuando subi todo a un servidor CentOS 7 dejo de funcionar y me muestra este error:

```
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server. Error Code: [-1] Diagnostic Message: null
```

Entiendo que es un error de conexion al servidor:

```
LDAP_LOGGING=true
LDAP_CONNECTION=default
LDAP_HOST=ldap.forumsys.com
LDAP_USERNAME=null
LDAP_PASSWORD=null
LDAP_PORT=389
LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=example,dc=com"
LDAP_TIMEOUT=5
LDAP_SSL=false
LDAP_TLS=false
```

Pero lo mas extraño que en local me funciona.
En el servidor CentOS 7 tiene activo el firewall y configurado el puerto 389 correctamente.
Creo que no tiene salida y no puedo conectarme a `ldap.forumsys.com` pero no se por que..

Answer (score 0):

Después de realizar los cambios en el archivo .env, has ejecutado el comando `php artisan config:cache`?
Ya que a veces la cache juega malos tragos.